# Chrome storage custom serialization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For example. I have something like this:

```
class Qwe {
constructor(q, w, e) {
    this.q = q;
    this.w = w;
    this.e = e;
}

toJSON() {
    return {q: this.q, w: this.w};
}
}
```

And i want to store object of this class in `chrome.storage`, but it would be something like this:

```
{q:q, w:w, e:e}
```

And i wonder if there is any way to custom serialization like here with `toJSON`, or if not how you would resolve this problem.

Comment: Not sure what you expect from JS. It's not C# or Java, you know. You'll have to do it manually. Maybe someone wrote a library for that, though.

Comment: Hmm, thought maybe there is something hide in `chrome.storage`.
So now i think it will be more efficient store this `e:e` too. Especially when object would store another object and so on.

Comment: Oh, you thought chrome.storage would invoke your toJSON() method just like JSON.stringify does. No, it [doesn't](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/base/json/json_writer.cc?type=cs&q=symbol:JSONWriter::BuildJSONString). The reason is performance I guess.

Comment: Yes, its why i added this method. I thought that `chrome.storage` sotore strings and invoke `toJSON()` but when it didn't work, then i looked into documentation.

Comment: Well, to reiterate my idea, you can replace the standard .set and .get methods in chrome.storage or use a better/simpler wrapper that processes toJSON when present. Also check if someone already wrote such a library.

Comment: @Konrad, do you still have a question here? If you've solved your own problem, please provide an answer and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do this is implement your own serialization (and perhaps deserialization) and call it on main object before store in `chrome.storage`:

```
...
let qwe = new Qwe("q", "w", "e");
...
let item = {qwe: qwe.serialize()}; // in this case toJSON()
chrome.storage.local.set(item);
...
```

**About implementation of serialization:**

I have created something like this for main object:

```
let mainObject = {
    //...
    //a lot of objects literals, arrays, and our classes (objects)
    //...
}

function serialize(sourceObject, object) {
    if(sourceObject instanceof Array) {
        if(object instanceof Array) {
            let id = sourceObject.push([]) - 1;
            object.forEach(item => {
                serialize(sourceObject[id], item);
            });
        } else if(object instanceof Object) {
            if(object.serializable) {
                sourceObject.push(object.serialize());
            } else {
                let id = sourceObject.push({}) - 1;
                serialize(sourceObject[id], object);
            }
        } else {
            sourceObject.push(object);
        }
    } else {
        for(let property in object) {
            if(object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if(object[property] instanceof Array) {
                    sourceObject[property] = [];
                    object[property].forEach(item => {
                        serialize(sourceObject[property], item);
                    });
                } else if(object[property] instanceof Object) {
                    if(object[property].serializable) {
                        sourceObject[property] = object[property].serialize();
                    } else {
                        sourceObject[property] = {};
                        serialize(sourceObject[property], object[property]);
                    }
                } else {
                    sourceObject[property] = object[property];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If object has property `serializable` then i know that it implements `serialize()` otherwise i go deeper. I don't know if this is optimal solution ;).

Usage:

```
let o = {
    mainObject: {}
};
serialize(o.mainObject, mainObject);
chrome.storage.local.set(o);
```